# Get-SPOTenant and Get-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction using Connect-PnPOnline

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I was trying to connect to SharePoint online via **Connect-SPOService** where I do not have a username/password and have only clientId and clientSecret. While surfing online I get https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258597/connect-sposervice-using-app-id-and-app-secret this link and it says you can do **Connect-SPOService** equivalent via **Connect-PnPOnline**. I have tried to connect **Connect-PnPOnline** like

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://org-admin.sharepoint.com -ClientId 7b2cd291-87e9-49fc-888e-xxxxxxxxxxxx -ClientSecret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And I can successfully connect. But I need **Get-SPOTenant** and **Get-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction** details via **Connect-PnPOnline** or Microsoft graph API. I am new to the Microsoft ecosystem and not sure how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

There are equivalent commands available in PnP PowerShell for the commands you are looking for.

Check these alternative commands:

1. For `Get-SPOTenant`: Use [Get-PnPTenant](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPTenant.html)
2. For `Get-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction`: Use [Get-PnPTenantSyncClientRestriction](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPTenantSyncClientRestriction.html)

**Update from comments**:

Use PnP PowerShell commands like this:

```
// Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://org-admin.sharepoint.com -ClientId 7b2cd291-87e9-49fc-888e-xxxxxxxxxxxx -ClientSecret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

// Get tenant details
Get-PnPTenant
```

You can also specify the tenant admin URL with `Connect-PnPOnline` command using `-TenantAdminUrl` parameter. Check documentation of `Connect-PnPOnline` for more information: [Connect-PnPOnline](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#parameters)

Comment: I am geting "Get-PnPTenant : Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://org-admin.sharepoint.com/. The app principal does not exist." error while running Get-SPOTenant command.

Comment: I was doing the same way as your updated answer but was unsuccessful. what would be TenantAdminUrl here?

Comment: You can go to SP admin center using URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2185219. Once you login, anything before `/_layouts/` in browser URL is your tenant admin URL. Generally, it is in same format as you are using like: `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/`.